# live server shows 404 error, but not on local, codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have four identical pages that only differs in some identifiers but the logic is very much the same. All of them works on localhost. Three of those pages works okay on live server, but one of them returns a 404 for some reasons I can't understand.

I use XAMPP 3.2.2 and Sublime for developing it on local. I moved it to GoDaddy Deluxe Linux for live. My Codeigniter version is 3.1.10.

I already tried answers from most of the questions on StackOverflow:

1. All controller and model names' first letters are capitalized in the file name and inside the file.
2. All of the .htaccess codes on here: https://github.com/tasmanwebsolutions/htaccess_for_codeigniter
3. I have two .htaccess files, one of them is inside the application folder, and one is outside. I don't know if that's confusing the system? But I have another website on a different hosting that has the same .htaccess files and they're working okay. And anyway, if that's confusing the system, why does it only affect one of the four identical pages?

**.htaccess outside application folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess inside application folder:**

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

**All of the controllers of the four files has this up top:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
//session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI

class Question1 extends CI_Controller
{
```

and the rest is normal code stuff that are working on three of those four files.

**In config. php I have:**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and base_url is great.

Models and views are okay, as far as I can see, and the rest of the website is functioning alright with the included .htaccess. My routes are working okay, as well.

I'm so lost right now.

PS. I have a custom 404 page. When I input assessment.com/index.php/question1 it shows that custom 404 page. But when I open assessment.com/question1 it shows codeigniter's own 404 page (and not my custom one, for some reasons). I think that tells something, I just don't know what.

EDIT

**Here's my routes.php:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'Error404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

I opted not to do
$route['question1'] = "Question1";
in routes because it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you able to write what the URL are, for the page that you're unable to see? And do you really need two `.htaccess`-files? ... Or could it be united in one htaccess-file? [This here](https://serverfault.com/questions/87676/how-to-echo-out-from-htaccess) is a method to write something from your `.htaccess`-file, which could be a help when debugging. And if it was me, then I'd go through my code, and try and write `<?php echo 'Does it reach this point'; die(); ?>`, to see where in the code the problem is.

Comment: the URL i can't access is http://assessment.com/question1 . I have a http://assessment.com/question2 and http://assessment.com/question3 that I can access without any problem. Their only differences are variable names and a couple of values. I tried combining both .htaccess files, it returns a website-wide error. Also, the .htaccess files I've provided are all of if. It's not very complicated to check line by line.

Comment: Try and add the entire .htaccess to your question (as an addition in the bottom), so I (and others) can see what you've tried.

Comment: Those two I've provided are the entire .htaccess files. There's nothing else in it.

Comment: In config $config['index_page'] = ''; and check withour index.php in url

Comment: I have this in config: $config['index_page'] = ''; and I already checked with and without index.php in URL. Still an error.

Comment: What do your routes look like, and which is the one which does not work?

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: To be clear - does it mean you have no routes for these URIs?  And your 4 URLs are `assessment.com/index.php/question1`, `.../question2`, ... etc?  And you have 4 Controllers in `application/controllers/Question1.php`, `application/controllers/Question2.php`, etc?  It is not documented AFAICT but AFAIK if you don't specify a route with a method name it will look for a method called `index` - do each of your controllers have one?  Which one is generating the 404?

Comment: I have 4 controllers: Question1.php, Question2.php, Question3.php and Question4.php and yes, they are inside the controller folder and have index() method in it. Their URLs are assessment.com/question1, assessment.com/question2, assessment.com/question3, assessment.com/question4 accordingly. No, they don't have $route['question1'] = "Question1";   (and so on) in the routes file. The assessment.com/question1 is what's generating the 404, everyone else is okay.

Comment: That is indeed very odd :-) Is there a reason you are using a custom `.htaccess` rather than [the one from the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)?  I can't see that being the problem, but with nothing else to go on better to rule that out.

Comment: I have tried the one from the docs as well, to no avail :/

Comment: Is it perhaps an issue with the hosting and the CI version? or no?

Comment: Does explicitly adding routes for all 4 URIs like `$route['questionX'] = 'questionX/index';` work? Anything in the logs? Try bumping up the log threshold 
 in your `config.php`. Try removing all your code and just doing `echo "questionX";` in each method, maybe the problem is in the code, not routing? I'd still suspect there is *something* about your `Question1` class or file or method that is somehow different.

Comment: Hey, would you mind putting that in as an answer instead of a comment? I think you're up to something!

Comment: Thanks, and glad we might be getting somewhere, but on SO answers should really be *answers*, not questions or suggestions.  If adding the routes works, let me know and I will add it :-)

Comment: It's actually not the routes. I tried adding $route['questionX'] = 'questionX/index'; in my routes and it didn't help. I echoed "questionx" in Question1/index() controller, and it appeared! So, it looks like it's my controller that has the problem. I am now in the process of fixing it, based on that opinion of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for the others who might come across the same problem.

Okay so user Don't Panic suggested I echo just "question x" in the problematic controller, and when I did that, the 404 error went away and it echoed the "question x." So definitely it's my controller that has the problem and not my routine or .htaccess files.

Now this controller is designed in such a way that it calls first an ID from the database before it shows anything. After I echoed "question x" I realized that the ID it is calling from my database has a value of zero. So, unsurprisingly, from the controller's point of view, the page doesn't exist! Hence the 404.

I've fixed it now by updating that table from my database and giving the ID a value it should already have had in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Check your APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT mode. You can find it on your project root_folder/index.php and at line no. 57.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Change the ENVIRONMENT mode into the development mode, that is

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Then refresh your applications again. If you see CodeIgniter default error you can understand your CodeIgniter application are running ok and check out the error.If it doesn't show any error then your .httaccess has any error. I solved it my 404 error with this code, you can check this out.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^asset.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I found this on line 56: define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');   I'm assuming I'm already at development mode? I also tried your .htaccess file, still an error.